# How to sort hash keys by their value in ruby 2.3.0

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, hash

I have this array:

```
data = [
  ['Frank', 33],
  ['Stacy', 15],
  ['Juan', 24],
  ['Dom', 32],
  ['Steve', 24],
  ['Jill', 24]
]
```

I took that and turned it into a hash so that I would have it be organized by keys and values, so that they would be easier to call individually. Which ended up giving me this

```
{"Frank"=>33, "Stacy"=>15, "Juan"=>24, "Dom"=>32, "Steve"=>24, "Jill"=>24}
```

I know in order to only see the keys I need to do `data.keys` and that by doing `data.keys.sort` I get the keys in alphabetical order.

I assume that I need to do something like `data.keys.sort_by { |key, value| value }` but whenever I run that I receive the hash keys in the original order.

Comment: It's difficult to do programmatically because you have keys that repeat. Otherwise, something like data.to_h.map { |k,v| v }.sort.map { |vv| {h.key(vv) => vv} } would work.

Comment: What's supposed to happen when you have values that are the same?

Comment: yeah ... for clarity, data.to_h.map { |k,v| v }.sort.map { |vv| {h.key(vv) => vv} } will work except that the __values__ repeat, not keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change the order of a hash, but you can sort the array before turning it into a hash:

```
data = [
  ['Frank', 33],
  ['Stacy', 15],
  ['Juan', 24],
  ['Dom', 32],
  ['Steve', 24],
  ['Jill', 24]
]

hash = data.sort_by(&:last).to_h
# => { "Stacy" => 15,
#      "Juan" => 24,
#      "Steve" => 24,
#      "Jill" => 24,
#      "Dom" => 32,
#      "Frank" => 33 }
```

If you already have a hash, then you'll have to turn it into an array, then sort it, and then turn it back into a hash, e.g. `hash.to_a.sort_by(&:last).to_h`.

Comment: That is very good to know, thank you! By doing -- hash = data.sort_by { |keys, values| values }.to_h it sorted them into the correct order too. Thank you. That is very helpful!

Comment: this isn't what was asked ... the question was how to sort keys by their value.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally,

> How to sort hash keys by their value in ruby 2.3.0?

if you have a hash like

```
hash = {"Frank"=>33, "Stacy"=>15, "Juan"=>24, "Dom"=>32, "Steve"=>24, "Jill"=>24}
```

then, hash can be simply sorted by `keys` or `values` but this will give you an `array` or `arrays` which can be converted to hash though.

```
hash.sort_by{|x,y| y}.to_h
# => {"Stacy"=>15, "Juan"=>24, "Steve"=>24, "Jill"=>24, "Dom"=>32, "Frank"=>33}
```

---

## For nested hashes

```
people = {
  :fred => { :name => "Fred", :age => 23 },
  :joan => { :name => "Joan", :age => 18 },
  :pete => { :name => "Pete", :age => 54 }
}

people.sort_by { |k, v| v[:age] }
# => [[:joan, {:name=>"Joan", :age=>18}],
#     [:fred, {:name=>"Fred", :age=>23}],
#     [:pete, {:name=>"Pete", :age=>54}]]
```

In this way, we could even sort by the :name key, if we so chose.